# JQuery - CSS Editor? Is there one?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a JQuery plugin that has a css editor? What I mean is something like this:

http://www.cssportal.com/css-style-editor/

Kind of like the dreamweaver style editor.

If there isn't something like this, Its probably not that hard to create, eh? :)

**Update:**

To be more clear, I would like to create my own css editor (or use a JQuery one) to replace the one that tinyMCE uses:  http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/tryit/jquery_version.php

Click on the style editor in the tinyMCE.

I would basically want to recreate that in JQuery, but would probably need to do some php backend stuff to save the changes and put it back into the tinyMCE editor.

Comment: If you use Chrome you can just right click an element, select Computed Style on the right hand side pane and edit whatever you like.

Comment: I would like to make a CSS editor for my clients inside of an application I am creating. :) Not for me to edit CSS

Comment: Then you need some back-end stuff to get and parse the CSS-files and store the personalized values after editing.
Not trivial, but absolutely interesting.

Comment: Thats what im thinking, probably not hard to code at all, but my only concern would be how to send those new css values into the inline style tag of that element with Jquery... maybe that should have been my question...

Comment: The syntax, techniques and examples for setting styles using jQuery is very well documented on the jQuery website.

Answer (score 5):

Are you looking for something like this: http://usejquery.com/posts/8/brosho-design-in-the-browser-jquery-plugin ?

Comment: Nope, but thanks :) I already got that link from a google search. Starting to think maybe what I want doesn't exist... lol

Comment: link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

[Jquery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) with the [ThemeRoller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) is basicly a JQuery CSS editor.

I have used it for a couple of sites, and it works well.

One of the major advantages is that, you can make the markup/functionality, and let the creative people use the [Firefox Bookmarklet](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/developertool/) for adjusting look and feel.

Comment: That is kind of what I would like, but for simple standard styles. Like background color, etc etc

Comment: Basicly what you need then is a server generated css-file (put the link in after the base-css-file to overwrite values).
And a form-page or similar to let your users store the values for background etc.
Make it as simple as possible for your own sake.
http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/easy-color-picker is a place to get some help for the ui